# JS syntax issue or using three.js THREE.ImageLoader in a cycle

Tags: javascript, three.js

Think its more javascript syntax issue then three.js but still..
I have an object "o = {}", with a textures that stored like this

```
o = {
    ...
    textures: {
        one: {  
            low: { t: new THREE.Texture(), url: 'http://i.imgur.com/tJ0uJPt.jpg' },
            normal: { t: new THREE.Texture(), url: 'http://i.imgur.com/wBB1nZN.jpg' }
        },
        two: {  
            low: { t: new THREE.Texture(), url: 'http://i.imgur.com/9JaoZNA.jpg' },
            normal: { t: new THREE.Texture(), url: 'http://i.imgur.com/p9wO18t.jpg' }
            hd: ...
            etc..
        }

        etc..
    }
    ...
}
```

What i need is a function that can load all this texture using THREE.ImageLoader.
Also, when all textures is loaded i want to run o.texturesOnLoad(); function.

Thats what i have now http://jsfiddle.net/NEXny/5/
But only the last texture of o.textures is working.. think i'm passing variables to loader.load( ... ) in wrong way;

Hope anyone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by wrapping loader.load(...) in self executing function.

```
(function(obj, texture) {
    if (current == total) {
        // last texture
        loader.load( texture.url, function (image){
            texture.t.image = image;
            texture.t.needsUpdate = true;

            obj.texturesOnLoad();
        });
    } else {
        loader.load( texture.url, function (image){
            texture.t.image = image;
            texture.t.needsUpdate = true;
        });
    }
})(this, this.textures[texture][quality]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NEXny/6/